# ASP.NET MVC Dialog Stumped

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jQuery's UI dialog to open a basic form. I want to submit that form and close the dialog. I am having trouble.

The parent window opens the dialog (which contains a partial view) from click and form is submitted, they the browser opens the partial view in the browser. I want it to do the form work and close the dialog.

Is there a way to do this VIA Ajax.SubmitForm or some other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an ideal solution and can't believe that I couldn't solve it earlier. Simply use Ajax.BeginForm using the OnSuccess function of the AjaxOptions.

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "CloseDialog" })) { %>
    <%= Html.Hidden("ID", ViewData["ID"]) %>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<% } %>

function CloseDialog() {
    $("#ImageCropModal").dialog("close");
}
```

This posts to the form without re-rendering the view. The I can close the dialog manually, after form post is successful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the onsubmit event of the form, send the form via Ajax, close the dialog and then `Return False` to prevent the browser from submitting the form again and doing a full page postback.